# How to add JDBC driver to Kafka Connect on DC/OS?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, mesos, apache-kafka-connect, dcos

running Kafka Connect 4.1.1 on DC/OS using the confluent community package. How can we upload or add our jdbc driver to the remote cluster?

Update: It's a package installed DC/OS catalog, which is a mesos framework, running docker images.

Comment: I assume these are Docker containers that are running?

Comment: Yes, through a mesos framework. Updated question. I asked the DC/OS community also. But nothing yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Script borrowed from [here (thanks to @rmoff)](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/gcp-pipeline/Installing_connectors_in_Docker_containers.adoc)

It's an example of overriding the Docker `CMD` with a bash script to download and extract the REST API source connector.

```
bash -c 'echo Installing unzip… && \
                curl -so unzip.deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-16+deb8u3_amd64.deb && \
                dpkg -i unzip.deb && \
                echo Downloading connector… && \
                curl -so kafka-connect-rest.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/rmoff-connectors/kafka-connect-rest.zip && \
                mkdir -p /u01/connectors/ && \
                unzip -j kafka-connect-rest.zip -d /u01/connectors/kafka-connect-rest && \
                echo Launching Connect… && \
                /etc/confluent/docker/run'
```

---

You'll need to [build your own Docker images](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/development.html#extending-the-docker-images) and publish them to a resolvable Docker Registry for your Mesos cluster, and then edit the Mesos Service to pull these images instead of the Confluent one.

For example, in your Dockerfiles, you would have

```
ADD http://somepath.com/someJDBC-driver.jar /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
```

Or `curl` rather than `ADD`, as shown in the Confluent docs (because it needs to extract that `.tar.gz` file).

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect

ENV MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION 5.1.39

RUN curl -k -SL "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    | tar -xzf - -C /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ --strip-components=1 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}-bin.jar
```

You can also use `confluent-hub install` to add other connectors that aren't JDBC JAR files

Comment: Yeah that much I figured. The issue is how do I tell the mesos framework to use that that specific docker image. I'll have to dig around. I'll up-vote your answer for now.

Comment: I'd guess the docker daemon settings on the machine, but DCOS might be able to setup a custom Docker registry, I'm not sure. Otherwise, you could just push to DockerHub

Comment: It's more complicated then that. I need to rebuild the framework. 1- I need to find the src of it first lol. Worst case I will deploy my own service using marathon and standard docker images.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "rebuild", `FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect` should be fine. Otherwise, you just download the OSS Confluent tarball

Comment: Yes that's all understood, the mesos framework is a bunch of YAML (worst case compiled code) files using the DC/OS mesos SDK: https://mesosphere.github.io/dcos-commons/developer-guide/. So I would have to download that framework and look for the docker image and change that. Technically the framework should have allowed to specify a "volume" to allow it to get the jars. Thats what happens when we wan't to use one click installs haha

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. I've not used those one click catalog things, though

Comment: Yeah certain things work great! Like I'm running the packaged Kafka and no complains, but when you need customization, you have to dig in...